# How would I instruct extconf.rb to use additional g++ optimization flags, and which are advisable?

Tags: c++, ruby, shared-libraries, compiler-optimization, extconf.rb

I'm using [Rice](http://rice.rubyforge.org/) to write a C++ extension for a Ruby gem. The extension is in the form of a shared object (.so) file.

This requires 'mkmf-rice' instead of 'mkmf', but the two (AFAIK) are pretty similar.

By default, the compiler uses the flags `-g -O2`. Personally, I find this kind of silly, since it's hard to debug with any optimization enabled. I've resorted to editing the Makefile to take out the flags I don't like (e.g., removing `-fPIC -shared` when I need to debug using `main()` instead of Ruby's hooks).

But I figure there's got to be a better way. I know I can just do

```
$CPPFLAGS += " -DRICE"
```

to add additional flags. But how do I remove things without editing the Makefile directly?

A secondary question: what optimizations are safe for shared objects loaded by Ruby? Can I do things like `-funroll-loops`? What do you all recommend?

It's a scientific computing project, so the faster the better. Memory is not much of an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is to append -O0 to CXXFLAGS, which will turn off optimization.  Later options will override earlier ones.

As far as safety for a plugin, you should be able to do anything that doesn't affect the ABI.  Without testing, I don't see why -funroll would.  Of course, safe does not imply better.  As noted by the man page, "-funroll-loops makes code larger, and may or may not make it run faster."

Comment: Append -O0 to what exactly? Just stick it on `$CPPFLAGS`?

Comment: @mohawk, it should actually be CXXFLAGS, which is the C++-specific variable.  CPPFLAGS will be passed to the C++ compiler, but it's actually for pre-processor options in general.  CXXFLAGS is also after CPPFLAGS in the [implicit rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

Comment: Thanks very much. Learn something new everyday. =)

Answer (score 2):

To define you use

`-D name=definition`

like you do in your example:

```
$CPPFLAGS += " -DRICE"
```

> -U name
>   Cancel any previous definition of name, either built in or provided with a -D option.

```
$CPPFLAGS += " -URICE"
```

Although I'm not sure if it'll help with undefining -O2 like you want it.